# Keyboard's event considered like mouse's click on the GUI

Tags: matlab, user-interface

I'm using GUI, I have 4 button in my GUI and my callback detect mouse and keyboard event.
Mouse event concerns click on button
Keyboard event concerns space press to play a .wav

When the position of mys cursor's mouse is on one of the 4 buttons, and I press space I've the following error

"Undefined function 'pushbutton4_KeyPressFcn' for input arguments of type 'struct'."

I didn't define any keyboard shortcut for the GUI's button, how can I avoid this error ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open the GUI in GUIDE.
Right click on the button and chose 'Property Inspector'.
Scroll down to the 'KeyPressFcn' field and delete the value.
Save the GUI and try again.

Comment: Perfect, didn't seen this value ! Thanks a lot !